# Unable to download from S3 via browser, signed in with Account ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-policy

I have the following policy:

```
"Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1660020066047",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET/*"
        }
    ]
```

I'm trying to access via browser (by signed in with the ACCOUNT_ID account) but I'm receiving the ACCESS_DENIED error, why?

If a put `"AWS": "*"` then I can see the files in the browser (obviously now they are public), but it's just to see that the policy works.

So I guess that even if I got "access" I can't see the files via browser.

Any hint?

NOTE: Public access block is already disabled.

Comment: It is very hard to access S3 objects via a browser with authentication. You will typically need a [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object. Can you show us how you are attempting to access the object (eg what the URL looks like)?

Comment: When you access via the browser the browser does not have AWS credentials, so the bucket blocks access

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I didn't create the signed URL and now I see it make senses , I'll try that, thanks!